# Clearing Form Input fields in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, next.js

I have a simple registration page in my next.js project (using typescript and react), but when I try to clear the Form input fields, I run into an error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: document is not defined
const usrInupt = document.getElementById("usernamefield") as HTMLInputElement
```

How can I clear the input fields but still have the createUserAccount() function running on the server only?

Here is my code:

```
//... the imports and page title
async function createUserAccount(data: FormData) {
    "use server"
    const username = data.get("usrname")
    const password = data.get("pswd")

    console.log(username+'@'+password)

    const usrInupt = document.getElementById("usernamefield") as HTMLInputElement
    const pswdInupt = document.getElementById("passwordfield") as HTMLInputElement

    usrInupt.value = ''
    pswdInupt.value = ''

}

export default function Register(){
    
    return (
    <>
    <div className="registerbox">
        <Image priority={true} src={topcircleimage} alt="Top Circle Image" width="0" height="0" className="topcircle"/>
        <h1>Register Page</h1>
        {/* <form action="/register.php" className="registerform">*/}
        <form action={createUserAccount} className="registerform">
            <p>Username</p>
            <input type="text" id="usernamefield" name="usrname" required minLength={1} maxLength={16} placeholder="Enter Username"/>
            <p>Password</p>
            <input type="password" id="passwordfield" name="pswd" required minLength={4} maxLength={16} placeholder="Enter Password"/>
            <input type="submit" name="" value="Register"/>
            <p id="bottom-text">Already have an account?</p>
            <Link href="/login">Login Here.</Link>
        </form>
    </div>
    </>
    )
}
```

Looking at other Stack Overflow questions, I couldn't find a valid solution.